# React router Link doesn't redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

Please see [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-cannon-kft4l?file=/src/App.js).

I'm having this code:

```
    <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/items/:itemId">
          <Item />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/items">
          <Items />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/items" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Expecting `/items` to be default route. `Items` is loading links for available items:

```
  const { url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Items</h1>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Link to={`${url}/${item}`}>{item}</Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Once an item link is clicked, I'm expecting the url to have the item in it, and to render `Item`.
`url` is `/items`, so everything should work out for `Switch` to render:

```
        <Route path="/items/:itemId">
          <Item />
        </Route>
```

However, it's staying at `/items`, and not even rendering `Items` component anymore. No error is shown. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

For router you are missing an `exact` props which is really important for your case

```js
<Route exact path="/items/:itemId" />
```

and inside your `Item` component you misspelled the `param` name, because in router it's `itemId` where the component has a different one `item`, so fixing it will make the param accessible(they should be exact match)

```js
export const Item = () => {
  const { itemId } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Item</h1>
      {itemId}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work, neither the other answer. Please see the updated sandbox.

Comment: It does work for me, but notice that you have to put the `/items` in URL and after navigation `codesandbox` sometimes doesn't load the new page correctly, so unfortunately you have to hit the refresh button manually (locally you wouldn't have such an issue)

Comment: For me what happens (locally as well) is that when on `/items`, clicking on an item it does change the url to `/items/:itemId`, but doesn't render the component, only if I reload the page.

Comment: I'll test locally then and find out what's going on!

Comment: it did work for me after replacing `Router` with `<BrowserRouter>` imported from `react-router-dom`, I don't know why `Router` didn't work despite I've used it before in some application and it didn't has an issue

Answer (score 1):

That because when it reaches the /items/:itemId Page the component get redirect back to /items , So the solution to this is just remove the redirect component

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/items/:itemId">
      <Item />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/items">
      <Items />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

Also there few other mistake which i saw in your code.In Item.jsx , your using

```
  const { item } = useParams();
```

This isn't going to the render the anything since it is undefined , that is because your are passing the /:itemId in Route. So try this instead

```
  const { itemId:item } = useParams();
```

here we are renaming the itemId to item inorder to accessable down in the code.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work, neither the other answer. Please see the updated sandbox.